# Increment or change variable each time Jess rule fires

Tags: clips, expert-system, jess

Is there a way to increment or change value of some variable each time rule fires?
I need that for every time rule fires introduce new value of the slot, since I will use this value for connectivity in the following example:
I have an electric circuit and rule that transforms delta to star. For every transform product is additional node. For simple network I have named it T, but for more complicated network I end up with network that is full of T nodes, since every time rule is triggered for another delta, I get a T node.

Comment: Do you need one variable for all rules, or one variable for one rule or variables for certain rules? Should the variable(s) be slots of a fact or is that not convenient? -- I fail to understand most of what you wrote, but probably that's immaterial anyway, and the essential information is missing.

Comment: I need one variable that will increment when certain rule fires, which will be at the RHS of the rule. It is only help variable which will be used to fill in some of the slots values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jess has a special kind of variables: global variable. They are visible in all parts of a program, including the RHSs of the rules. To create, use `defglobal`, e.g.

```
(defglobal ?*firecount* = 0)
```

Note that the asterisks are mandatory.

You use them just like any other variable:

```
(++ ?*firecount*)
(printout t "fire counter = " ?*firecount* crlf)
```

Note that not even `reset` clears a global. - Refer to the Jess manual for additional details.